# How to get window title correctly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

can I do the following to get the window's title of the another application

```
char window_text[256];
LRESULT lResult = SendMessageA(pMouseHook->hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(window_text) / sizeof(*window_text), (LPARAM)window_text);
printf("Copied %d characters. Contents: %s\n", lResult, window_text);
```

or should I first allocate the global memory and use it instead of the local char array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A local array is fine; the system automatically marshals pointers across process boundaries for system-defined messages (0 through `WM_USER-1`). A `char` array, however, is not so great. Use `wchar_t` instead; [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) has been using Unicode for well over 2 decades now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use a local character array. Of course, if the title is longer than the buffer you provide then the returned value will be truncated.

For a window is a different process you might consider `GetWindowText` instead. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) says:

> If the target window is owned by the current process, GetWindowText causes a WM_GETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or control. If the target window is owned by another process and has a caption, GetWindowText retrieves the window caption text. If the window does not have a caption, the return value is a null string. This behavior is by design. It allows applications to call GetWindowText without becoming unresponsive if the process that owns the target window is not responding. However, if the target window is not responding and it belongs to the calling application, GetWindowText will cause the calling application to become unresponsive.

Comment: But it also says "To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText"

Comment: Or is it related to the controls only, not the window itself?

Comment: `GetWindowText` is for top level windows with captions

Comment: So if I want to get the top-level window caption of another application then I should use GetWindowText function, but if I want to get text of some non-top window caption then I should use SendMessage, right?

Comment: Probably. Why do you want to get the text of windows in other processes?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Yes, use `GetWindowText()` for top-level window titles, and `WM_GETTEXT` for child window content.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: there are plenty of legitimate reasons to retrieve window titles. The *why* is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's why I answered the question at hand and asked about the motivation in a comment. It's not uncommon for people to think that they have the solution to a problem, but there may be better solutions.